# Text mining: How to solve this error message during the tokenization?

Tags: javascript, r

```
suppressWarnings(library(RWeka))
tokenizer <- function(x) 
NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2))


amzn_c_tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(
  amzn_cons_corp, 
  control = list(tokenize = tokenizer)
)
```

below code is the traceback of the error during the tokenization
Could you kindly help that why there is an error and how to solve it
Really appreciate

**traceback code**

```
'Error in .jcall("RWekaInterfaces", "[S", "tokenize", .jcast(tokenizer, : java.lang.NullPointerException'
```

10.

```
stop(structure(list(message = "java.lang.NullPointerException", 
call = .jcall("RWekaInterfaces", "[S", "tokenize", .jcast(tokenizer, "weka/core/tokenizers/Tokenizer"), 
.jarray(as.character(control)), .jarray(as.character(x))), 
jobj = <S4 object of class structure("jobjRef", package = "rJava")>), .Names = c("message", ...
```

9.

```
.jcheck()
```

8.

```
.jcall("RWekaInterfaces", "[S", "tokenize", .jcast(tokenizer, "weka/core/tokenizers/Tokenizer"), 
.jarray(as.character(control)), .jarray(as.character(x)))
```

7.

```
NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 1, max = 2))
```

6.

```
.tokenize(doc)
```

5.

```
FUN(X[[i]], ...)
```

4.

```
 lapply(X, FUN, ...)
```

3.

```
mclapply(unname(content(x)), termFreq, control)
```

2.

```
TermDocumentMatrix.VCorpus(amzn_cons_corp, control = list(tokenize = function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 1, max = 2)))
```

1.

```
TermDocumentMatrix(amzn_cons_corp, control = list(tokenize = function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 1, max = 2))))
```

Comment: You may want to consider updating your question with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Oops will update it soon.

Answer (score 0):

You need to resolve NAs in your dataset 'amzn_cons_corp'

You can either use this:

```
amzn_cons_corp[which(is.na(amzn_cons_corp))] <- "NullUpdated"
```

Or you can use:

```
amzn_cons_corp = amzn_cons_corp[!is.na(amzn_cons_corp)]
```